# Rendering Chart JS via a Slot in Lightning Web Components

Tags: salesforce, shadow-dom, custom-element, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to render a Chart JS canvas via a slot;

chartWrapper.html

```html
<template>
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <slot name="chart"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

chartWrapperContainer.html

```html
<c-chart-wrapper>
    <canvas slot="chart" class="donut" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
</c-chart-wrapper>
```

The chart does not render and the canvas in the rendered Markup shows 0 width and height. Rendering without the slot works well; I need to wrap it into a slot for structural reasons.

What could be wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was sorted out by wrapping the canvas in a `div`; made some logical sense to me not to push a plain 'photo' into a slot whose internals it's unaware of.

```html
<!-- chartWrapper.html -->
<template>
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <slot name="chart"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- chartWrapperContainer.html -->
<c-chart-wrapper>
  <div slot="chart">
    <canvas class="donut" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
  </div>
</c-chart-wrapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could set a CSS property that defines the Custom Element as a `block`, or `inline-block` through the **:host** pseudo-class. (By default a custom element has its `display` value set to `inline`.)

Then you can set its `height` and `width` or let the default ones:

```
<!-- chartWrapper.html -->
<template>
   <style>
      :host {
          display: inline-block ;
          width: 50% ;
          height: 200px ;
      }
   </style>  
   <slot></slot>
</template>
```